# ASP.NET ITemplate with TemplateInstance.Multiple

Tags: asp.net, templates, user-controls

I can't seem to find any examples on how to implement ITemplates with multiple instances. All I need to do is build out a navigation that has a template for the content of each navigation item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your control is not a databound control, you can solve the problem by something as follows. But, I haven't tested it.

```
public class FooItem : WebControl, INamingContainer
{

    protected override CreateChildControls()
    {
        Control placeHolder = this.FindControl(((Foo)this.Parent).ItemPlaceHolderId);
        if (placeHolder != null)
        {
            // Add some controls to the placeHolder.
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
public class Foo : WebControl, INamingContainer
{

    public ITemplate ItemTemplate { get; set; }

    public string ItemPlaceHolderId
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }

    public FooItemCollection Items
    {
        get { ... }
    }

    protected override CreateChildControls()
    {
        foreach (FooItem item in this.Items)
        {
            this.ItemTemplate.InstantiateIn(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at documentation of creating a data-bound templated control.

Unfortunately, the best documentation I've found is from .NET 1.1:
[Developing a Templated Data-Bound Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719971(VS.71).aspx).

---

Note from MSDN:

> This TemplateInstanceAttribute class
> is optional. If a template property is
> not extended with a
> TemplateInstanceAttribute class, the
> default value, the Multiple field, is
> used.

So any `ITemplate` example that does not use the `TemplateInstanceAttribute` is using `TemplateInstance.Multiple`.

Comment: Though this will probably help I actually don't need or want my control to be databound.

Comment: I didn't suggest that your control should be databound, only that you should look at the documentation, as it was likely the only documentation of creating multiple instances of a single `ITemplate` parameter.